# I can't update my iPhone 4 v7.1.2 (11d257)

Tags: iphone

I tried updating apps and it directed to enter password for a different Apple ID which is not mine. Please what should I do.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings -> iTunes Store & App Store, and click on the apple account (first thing on the list)

[image]

Then click Sign out and reboot

[image]

Go back to Settings -> iTunes Store & App Store and enter login + password for your account

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Delete the App and re-install using your own Apple ID